# access custom customer attribute in email template

Tags: email-templates, custom-attributes, magento2.4.2

I have created a custom attribute for customers.
In the next step I want to access it in email templates. For example in the password forgotten template.

The variable "customer" contains the following information:

```
            ...
            [email] => doe@example.com
            [firstname] => John
            [lastname] => Doe
            [prefix] => Mr.
            [gender] => 0
            [store_id] => 1
            [website_id] => 1
            [addresses] => Array
                (
                )

            [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
            [custom_attributes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [attribute_code] => my_custom_attribute
                            [value] => 1234
                        )

                )

            [name] => John Doe
        )
```

The only way that works is to use `{{var customer.custom_attributes.0.value}}`. But this doesn't seem to be a reasonable way, because the array key "0" is not reliably the one of my_custom_attribute.

How can I access my_custom_attribute reliable?

*side note:*
*Creating a plugin for the EmailNotification::getFullCustomerData() method doesn't work either, because this method is private.*

Comment: Did you find a solution for it? I have found a way for it.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this we need to pass dynamic data through handle.First this is my data which i got in "custom_attributes" - https://prnt.sc/10cvmir

Please follow below steps.Please create any named layout file in any of your module , here i have created "custom_attribute_email.xml"

> Step 1: Please create file "custom_attribute_email.xml" under path
> PackageName/Vendor/view/frontend/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Product List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.customer.info" template="PackageName_Vendore::customer/email.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Step 2: Please create email.phtml file under path
> PackageName/Vendor/view/frontend/templates/customer

```
<?php $customer = $block->getCustomer(); ?>
<?php foreach ($customer['custom_attributes'] as $key => $data): ?>
    <p><strong><?php echo $data['attribute_code']; ?></strong>:<span><?php echo $data['value']; ?></span></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Now please open any of your email template , here i have taken forgot password email template. Then in your email template add the below code like this - https://prnt.sc/10cvqqh

{{layout handle="custom_attribute_email" customer=$customer area="frontend"}}

**Note :** Your template variable customer should be object

Output will be :- https://prnt.sc/10cvg97

This code will perfectly work for you. Please change code in phtml file according to your need. Please check and let me know on this.

**Thanks
Cheers!**

Comment: Does this work with Version 2.4.2? $block->getCustomer() returns always null. :(
[Trying to access array offset on value of type null]

Comment: Yes , it will work.Your template variable customer object should be passed like this {{layout handle="custom_attribute_email" customer=$customer area="frontend"}}

Comment: Please follow all steps to make it work. I have practically checked after that i have posted here.

Comment: Got it: It only works with template files. If I set up a template via Backend, it won't work. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes , it won't work. I have shown you just for front end according to your requirement.

Comment: My answer will satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Can you please approve and upvote this?

Comment: <?php $customer = $block->getCustomer(); ?> not working please any suggestion.@ZealousWeb

Comment: Which magento version you are working ?

Comment: Have you added like - https://prnt.sc/15lshsd ?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work for me as well, always getting null $customer = $block->getCustomer();

Answer (score 0):

This is a reasonably well answer, but not as comprehensive as I want it to be.
The custom attributes are only accessable with template files, not with templates that are [user defined](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/email-template-message.html)

I created a plugin for `Magento\Framework\Reflection\CustomAttributesProcessor` which isn't the perfect way I guess, but much more versatile. It replaces the array_keys with the corresponding attribute_code, so you can access it via `{{var customer.custom_attributes.my_custom_attribute.value}}`

As far as I can tell, it doesn't break anything else either.

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- creates accessable custom attribute keys with attribute code -->
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Reflection\CustomAttributesProcessor">
        <plugin name="Vendor_Module_Reflextion_CustomAttributesProcessorPlugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Reflection\CustomAttributesProcessorPlugin" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Plugin\Reflection\CustomAttributesProcessorPlugin

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Reflection;

use Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValue;

/**
 * creates DataOutputArray which is reliable accessible from email templates
 */
class CustomAttributesProcessorPlugin
{
  public function afterBuildOutputDataArray($subject, $result) {
    $customAttributes = [];
    foreach ($result as $attribute) {
        $customAttributes[$attribute[AttributeValue::ATTRIBUTE_CODE]] = 
        [
            AttributeValue::VALUE => $attribute[AttributeValue::VALUE],
            AttributeValue::ATTRIBUTE_CODE => $attribute[AttributeValue::ATTRIBUTE_CODE]
        ];
    }

    return $customAttributes;
  }
}
```

Can anyone confirm?